Tombstones not being removed in a Cassandra database
I think tombstones are not being deleted in a Cassandra 4.1.7 table.
The table's gc_grace_seconds = 345600
Even after running nodetool garbagecollect (much later than 4 days after the deletion), if I run nodetool tablestats I get the following:

The size on disk does not decrease either after doing garbagecollect.
I'm not sure if in the past I ran nodetool compact (which I think would mean I need to keep using it?)
Side question, How can I get tablestats to return more recent info (instead of from 2024-12-12)
Thanks

It sounds like compaction is not running. It sucks, but that's what can happen if it gets run manually even once.
Try running a SELECT * FROM system.compaction_history. If the keyspace.table in question hasn't had it run in a while, you may need to start scheduling it to run on a recurring basis.
Once compaction has run for that table, have another look at nodetool tablestats again. If there isn't a significant improvement, then some other issue could be at play here.
Edit 20241223

I do see rows for this table in the compaction_history table including from today. The bytes_out field shows slightly lower numbers than the bytes_in field. Does that mean I should NOT run nodetool compact?

I would still not run nodetool compact.
Are snapshots enabled? If compactions are indeed running, it's possible that an old snapshot has a hard link to one or more SSTables. If so, see about cleaning up some of the old snapshots and then see if compaction will run again on its own.

Thanks @Aaron I do see rows for this table in the compaction_historytable including from today. The bytes_out field shows slightly lower numbers than the bytes_in field. Does that mean I should NOT run nodetool compact?

@adinas edit made.
